# C++ sorting in lexicographically order

Tags: c++

here is my code :

```
 sort(S1.begin(), S1.begin()+4);
for ( int i = 0; i < S1.capacity(); i++ )
cout << S1[i]<<endl;
```

I am getting this :
a
aa
aab
ab
b
a
aa
aac
ac
c

but I should be getting this:
"a", "aa", "aab", "aac", "ab", "ac", "b", "c"

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You are only sorting the first 3 elements. How about sorting everything by doing `sort(S1.begin(), S1.end())`?

Comment: Read up in what `capacity()` does. It probably isn't what you think

Comment: There are many potential reasons for the output. Create a [mcve] and we may be able to tell you which of the reasons it is, rather than guess.

Answer (score 1):

End iterator is incorrect - you should use `S1.end()` instead of `S1.begin()+4`.

Answer (score 0):

- Use `end()` iterator.
- Use `size()`

This might work more like intended

```
sort(S1.begin(), S1.end());
for ( int i = 0; i < S1.size(); i++ ) {
    cout << S1[i] << endl;
}
```

You could also:

- use `std::size_t` instead of (signed) `int`
- use `++i` instead of
  `i++`

but these are just details.